# Rename a local variable of type class in all classes

Tags: java, eclipse

I have this line in about 50 java files :

```
Employee emp = EmployeeFactory.getEmployee(empId);
```

Used like :

```
public void someMethod(Some params){
   Employee emp = EmployeeFactory.getEmployee(empId);
}
```

There is a change in how the factory gets an emp and now I want to change it to :

```
SuperEmployee emp = EmployeeFactory.getEmployee(empId);
```

Employee needs to be changed to SuperEmployee and the imports need to be organized. I can select the project and do a Shift+ctrl+0 and that will fix the imports, but I am not able to make the Employee as SuperEmployee change in all files.

Is there a way this can be done using an eclipse feature ? 
I have tried a few options from the Refactor menu but none of it seems to help.

Comment: That looks like it's a *local* variable, not an instance variable...

Comment: It can be done... but not sure how atm :-)

Comment: Instead of changing the code in 50 different places, implement `SuperEmployee` to extend `Employee` and you're good to go!

Comment: @JonSkeet Edited the title. Its scattered around in the code base and about 95% of it is used as a local variable. I am guessing a change in the variable name would take care of instance and local variables ?

Comment: @alfasin That aint an option mate

Comment: @happybuddha No. Eclipse will only refactor a variable within a particular scope.

Comment: Don't you just want to rename the *class* or change the signature of `getEmployee()`? Your variable names aren't changing anywhere.

Comment: @adarshr What if, the scope is the entire project ? Don't work that way ?

Comment: Seems like a job for a text editor.

Comment: @happybuddha and why is that ?

Comment: Just say "Ommm" and start editing.  You'll be done before anyone comes up with a better idea.

Comment: @happybuddha So, use your friendly neighborhood "rename class" or "change signature" refactorings. Which I'm sure Eclipse can do but I won't rattle off the shortcut for you because I've stopped inflicting that IDE on myself a while ago.

Answer (score 3):

Just refactor the name of `Employee` class to `SuperEmployee`. Make sure you make a copy of the original `Employee` and `SuperEmployee` somewhere else.

Then replace the refactored `SuperEmployee` with the original `SuperEmployee`. Also replace the original `Employee` back.

To refactor, select the `Employee` type. Don't do it on the variable.

Comment: This is probably what I'd do, though it's a hack.

Comment: Yes it is a hack. But you want to get the job done in the least steps accurately, no?

Comment: You are presuming I have access to Employee class, which I dont. Text editing is what I have done. I dont know where Rohit Jains answer disappeared, but thats what worked for me

Comment: Well, even if you don't have access, you could still hack your way by creating that temporary class locally (and removing the original class from your classpath). I agree a text-replace would be easier. But this is more reliable as it wouldn't replace ocurrences of `Employee` inside comments and JavaDoc (unless you want it).